# Need to calculate elapsed time over a "shifting window" (PHP)

Tags: php

I need to calculate multiple sleep events over a rolling 24- and 48- hour period.

The time calculations themselves are not problematic, it's how to deal with the rolling period.

What I mean by the 'rolling period' is as follows:

Shift worker's sleep is recorded in seconds elapsed with a start time. This is easy to manage.

But what I need to capture is how much sleep the shift worker has had in the 24 hours and 48 hours prior to a specific time, for example, 4pm. But the specific time varies.

So, our shift worker sleeps on September 1 from 01:00 to 08:00, and has a day off.
She sleeps again on September 1 from 22:00 until 06:00 September 2 and starts work at 06:30 on September 2.

I need the algorithm to calculate how much sleep she has had in the 24 hours prior to the 6:30am shift (ie since 6:30 on 1 September), and for the 48 hours before.

I can't even think how to describe that simply, let along make an algorithm.

All I can think of to do is have an array of 48 elements, each representing an hour, and at the time of recording sleep populate each array with the portion of each hour slept, then roll the array over every hour.

Over to the brains trust?

Comment: How are the sleep times and work times stored? Can you show me your variables. IT may help to know how this is recorded in the db as well.

Comment: Hi @SmithSmithy. I haven't yet coded that part of the project yet because I wanted to keep an open mind. The data comes in using a text format for the sleep-start time that I'll use string functions to parse (the raw format over which I have no control is like this: April 28, 2014 at 06:08AM) and the elapsed time is in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to deal with date or time calculations in php is with [DateTime objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).  I'll have to make some assumptions about the format of your data, but from my experience this setup is common.

```
<?php

/** Your data */
$sleepCycles = array(
    /** Dates as YYYY-MM-DD and times as HH:ii:ss  */
  array('sleepid'=>1,'startdate'=>'2014-01-01','starttime'=>'08:00:00','lengthinseconds'=>28800),
  array('sleepid'=>2,'startdate'=>'2014-01-05','starttime'=>'17:00:00','lengthinseconds'=>28800)
    );

/** The start and end of your rolling check period. 
 * $hoursToCheck and $start should be input.  
 * $start should be in format "YYYY-mm-dd HH:ii:ss"
 */
$rollStart = new DateTime( $start );  
$rollEnd = new DateTime( $start );
/**  $hoursToCheck should be a number or a string that resolves to a number.  */
$rollEnd->modify('+'.$hoursToCheck.' hour');


/** The counter for how much sleep falls within your check */
$amountSleptInSeconds = 0;  
foreach ( $sleepCycles as $sc )
{
  $startDateObj = new DateTime( $sc['startdate'] .' '. $sc['starttime'] );
  $endDateObj = new DateTime( $sc['startdate'] .' '. $sc['starttime'] );
  $endDateObj->modify('+'.$sc['lengthinseconds'].' second');

  /**
   * If either the start or end of the sleep cycle fall 
   * inside the rolling check period,
   * some part of the sleeping counts.
   */
  if ( $rollStart <= $startDateObj && $startDateObj >= $rollEnd )
  {
    /** Get the time that counts. Note it may not be the entire sleep period. 
     * If both ends of the sleep also falls inside the check, count the entire
     * length.  If not, only count the sleep that is inside.
     */
    if ( $endDateObj >= $rollEnd )
    {  $amountSleptInSeconds += $sc['lengthinseconds'];  }
    else
    {  
      $countMeInterval = $startDateObj->diff($rollEnd , TRUE);  
      $amountSleptInSeconds += $countMeInterval->format('%s');
    }
    
  }
  else if ( $rollStart <= $endDateObj && $endDateObj >= $rollEnd )
  {
    if ( $rollStart <= $startDateObj )
    {  $amountSleptInSeconds += $sc['lengthinseconds'];  }
    else
    {
      $countMeInterval = $rollEnd->diff($startDateObj , TRUE);
      $amountSleptInSeconds += $countMeInterval->format('%s');
    }
    
  }
}
    
print 'Within time period '
    .$rollStart->format('M j, Y g:ia').' - '
    .$rollEnd->format('M j, Y g:ia')
    .' (inclusive of end points) I found this amount of seconds of sleep: '
    .$amountSleptInSeconds;
?>
```